# .htaccess resolve relative path issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm new to .htaccess files. In my website i have page for users to search books by its category and sort by some parameters. real page url is like this. I have used few css and js files with relative paths. Ex: `<link href="../css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">`

> www.example.com/post/index.php?cat=science-fiction&sort=date

I have modified this url by using .htaccess file. for more meaningful url experience.

```
#Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

#Rewrite for ads.php
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) index.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]
```

I wanted to have my urls like this. and Its working.

> www.example.com/post/science-fiction
>
> www.example.com/post/science-fiction?sort=date

But my problem is, when user enters `"/"` end of the url. Page cant load css or js files. I want to Redirect or Ignore `"/"` end of the Url.

Problem with this URL

> www.example.com/post/science-fiction/
>
> www.example.com/post/science-fiction/?sort=date

How to resolve this changing .htaccess file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

For long term approach consider using absolute path in css like this:

```
<link href="/css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Currently i'm testing this in localhost. This code redirects to `http://localhost/science-fiction` or `http://localhost/science-fiction` how to redirect to `http://localhost/Project/post/science-fiction` or `http://localhost/Project/post/science-fiction?sort=date`

Comment: Its working. I changed it to R=404. Now it redirects to 404.